# How to sort javascript's array of objects by multiple property value

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have an array of Objects that contains the `fYear` and `FQtr` keys. My goal is to sort by `FQtr` keys and  `fYear`. Would you please help?

##### Original Data

```js
const data = [
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W10"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W11"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W12"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W13"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W2"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q4", "FQtr": "W1"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W3"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W4"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q4", "FQtr": "W2"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W5"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W6"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W7"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W8"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W9"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q4", "FQtr": "W4"},
    { "fYear": "QTD", "FQtr": "QTD"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q4", "FQtr": "W3"}
]
```

#### Expected Sorted Data

```js
const data = [
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W2"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W3"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W4"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W5"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W6"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W7"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W8"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W9"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W10"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W11"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W12"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W13"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q4", "FQtr": "W1"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q4", "FQtr": "W2"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q4", "FQtr": "W3"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q4", "FQtr": "W4"},
    { "fYear": "QTD", "FQtr": "QTD"}
]
```

#### My Approach

```js
function sortFQtr( a, b ) {
    const [prevVal, nextVal] = [Number.parseInt(a.FQtr.substring(1)), Number.parseInt(b.FQtr.substring(1))];
  if ( prevVal < nextVal ) return -1;
  if ( prevVal > nextVal) return 1;
  return 0;
}

// ["FY22 Q4", "FY22 Q3", "QTD"]
 var fYears = data.map(value => value.fYear).filter( (value, index, _arr) => _arr.indexOf(value) == index);
```

Comment: You don't need to convert the `fYear` parts to integer.  If those are not equal, you can do a string compare.  The `FQtr` is harder because there are digits, but you have most of the code in place.

Comment: Will you need to parse the data at some point or will you just use the strings everywhere? If you are going to parse the strings anyway, then you can use your parsing functions to guide your sorting algorithm. If not, then using [`String.prototype.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) is the simplest approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put everything inside the `.sort` callback. While you're comparing the `FQtr`s properly, you also need to factor in the `fYear` values in the same function.

`localeCompare` will make this easy - lexiographically, FY22 Q3 is followed by FY22 Q4, which is then followed by QTD. Sort by that difference - and if there is no difference, then sort by the FQtr property, which can also be done with `localeCompare` (with the numeric option).

```js
const data = [
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W10"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W11"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W12"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W13"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W2"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q4", "FQtr": "W1"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W3"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W4"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q4", "FQtr": "W2"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W5"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W6"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W7"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W8"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q3", "FQtr": "W9"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q4", "FQtr": "W4"},
    { "fYear": "QTD", "FQtr": "QTD"},
    { "fYear": "FY22 Q4", "FQtr": "W3"}
];

data.sort((a, b) => (
  a.fYear.localeCompare(b.fYear)
  || a.FQtr.localeCompare(b.FQtr, 'en', { numeric: true })
));
console.log(data);
```